# How to initialise a 2D array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, pseudocode

I've been given the pseudo-code:

```
    for i= 1 to 3
        for j = 1 to 3
            board [i] [j] = 0
        next j
    next i
```

How would I create this in python?

(The idea is to create a 3 by 3 array with all of the elements set to 0 using a for loop).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you really want to use `for`-loops:

```
>>> board = []
>>> for i in range(3):
...     board.append([])
...     for j in range(3):
...         board[i].append(0)
... 
>>> board
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

But Python makes this easier for you:

```
>>> board = [[0]*3 for _ in range(3)]
>>> board
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: I can do this using this as well: `nums = [[0]*4]*4` and it works fine. Is it right method?

Comment: @MehulMohan No, because each sublist will really be the same object. Try doing `nums[0][0] = 1` and see what `nums` becomes.

Comment: Woah @arshaji can you give a detailed reason why did that happen?

Answer (score 4):

```
arr=[[0,0,0] for i in range(3)] # create a list with 3 sublists containing [0,0,0]
arr
Out[1]: [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

If you want an list with 5 sublists containing 4 0's:

```
In [29]: arr=[[0,0,0,0] for i in range(5)]

In [30]: arr
Out[30]: 
[[0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

The range specifies how many sublists you want, ranges start at 0, so ranges 4 is `0,1,2,3,4`.
 gives you five `[0,0,0,0]`

Using the list comprehension is the same as:

```
arr=[]
for i in range(5):
    arr.append([0,0,0,0])

arr
[[0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer?

Answer (score 2):

If you want something closer to your pseudocode:

```
board = []
for i in range(3):
    board.append([])
    for j in range(3):
        board[i].append(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

numpy has something for this:

```
numpy.zeros((3,3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the style of pseudocode given or simply just use a python one liner

chess_board = [[x]*3 for _ in range(y)]  --> list comprehension

or you can use the plain loop style of other languages like java. I prefer the one liner as it looks much nicer and cleaner.